# How low can I make the source impedance of a PIC16F887 ADC?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, adc, microchip

Microchip recommends 10K for the maximum source impedance of the ADC, but it says nothing about the minimum value. How low can I make the source impedance ? It is possible to damage something if it's to low ?

Comment: As long as the Voltage stays within Abs. Max range. the Rs can be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot damage it provided you don't exceed the pin voltage range, which is in this case from -0.3V to Vdd+0.3V.

You can guarantee that with a Zener diode (connected with cathode to the pin and anode to ground, rated the same as your Vdd is), but as long as the source itself gets the power from the Vdd rail (opamp?), it is not necessary.

The device itself has got clamp diodes at each pin (google CMOS input protection) which clamp the voltage to the supply rails, but better not try that, you could damage the MCU and/or its surroundings easily.